# Can't get the same text style like in photoshop

Tags: css

This question was probably asked tons of times already, and i know that photoshop renders text completely differently from browsers, but perhaps some css guru could help me get this text to looks as much close to how it looks in PS as possible:

[image]

The most closest i got is:

```
color: #666;
font-size: 11px;
font-family: 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
```

But it looks to bold, and if i remove bold it's to thin...

Comment: What exactly are you using in PhotoShop? 12pt Arial? So why are to trying to get the same using some different font in a much smaller size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `text-shadow` property to anti-alias your font and can give boldness a lil without using `font-weight: bold;` and you can add `letter-spacing` too like this : [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rZezr/)

HTML

```
<div class="demo">Music 1</div>​
```

CSS

```
.demo {
   color: #515151;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-family: arial,sans-serif;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #515151;
   letter-spacing: .1em;
}
```

​

Comment: and then how to add sharp to text

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a less shadowy, more bold/sharp effect, you could try using multiple short-distance shadows as an alternative:

```
text-shadow: 0 0 .1px, 0 0 .1px, 0 0 .1px;
```

However, this will most likely be a performance hog when used on larger piles of text.